# SVN android studio "Import into version control" => "Import into subversion" option not displayed

Tags: android, android-studio, tortoisesvn

trying to use `SVN tortoise` with `Android Studio 2.2 Preview 2` and follows this tutorial [Using SVN in Android Studio](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs65/svn/androidstudio.html)

Problem:"Import into version control" => *"Import into subversion"* option is not displayed .

[image: Image of that problem]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform the following steps to `Integrate Subversion`.

1. Go to `Settings`
2. Check `Plugins and mark Subversion integration`
3. Click `Apply`
4. Then restart `Android Studio`.